# ¿Cómo aumentar progressbar mientras se ejecuta un hilo?

Tags: java, netbeans, hilos, jvm

tengo un programa que al llegar a cierta línea del código, se bloquea la JVM. Para solventarlo he metido esa tarea en un hilo, y mientras tanto he puesto un progressbar que se va rellenando. El problema es que el progressbar no hace nada. Tengo esta clase que implementa runnable, y que realiza la tarea pesada:

```
public class PDFLoader implements Runnable {
private JProgressBar progressBar;
private File f;
private PDDocument docu;
private PDDocument clone;
private String out;

public PDFLoader(JProgressBar progressBar, File f) {
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.f = f;
    this.out = out;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        // ESTA línea tiene la carga pesada
        docu = PDDocument.load(f);
        
        /*
        Código irrelevante
        */

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hecho");  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha habido un error");
        System.out.println(e);
    }  
}

public PDDocument getPDDocument() {
    return docu;
}
}
```

Seguidamente, implemento el Worker en otra clase:

```
        File f = new File("ruta del fichero");
        
        SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // Creo un objeto de la clase que realiza la tarea
                PDFLoader loader = new PDFLoader(jprogressBar, f);
                // Creo un hilo y lo inicio
                Thread thread = new Thread(loader);
                thread.start();    
                
                // Mientras el hilo está vivo, se recoge el progreso
                while (thread.isAlive() == true) {
                    // Actualiza el progressbar en función del progreso
                    int progress = (int)((float) loader.getPDDocument().getCurrentAccessPermission().getPermissionBytes());
                    publish(progress);                  
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

                return null;
            }
            
            @Override
            protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                // Actualiza el progressbar en la GUI
                jprogressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
            }
        };
        
        // Ejecuto el proceso.
        worker.execute();
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un problema en la implementación del `SwingWorker`, ya que el progreso del `JProgressBar` no se actualiza. El problema es que la tarea pesada se está ejecutando en un hilo separado, pero el proceso que actualiza la barra de progreso se está ejecutando en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario (UI), que se bloquea mientras se realiza la tarea pesada.

Puedes mover la línea `docu = PDDocument.load(f);` a un método separado en la clase `PDFLoader`, y llamarlo en el método `doInBackground()` del `SwingWorker`.

Además, puedes actualizar el `JProgressBar` en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario usando el método s`etProgress()` del `SwingWorker`. Esto garantiza que la actualización de la barra de progreso se realice en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario.

**Posible implementación:**

```
public class PDFLoader implements Runnable {
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private File f;
    private PDDocument docu;
    private PDDocument clone;
    private String out;
    
    public PDFLoader(JProgressBar progressBar, File f) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.f = f;
        this.out = out;
    }
    
    public void loadDocument() throws IOException {
        docu = PDDocument.load(f);
        // Código adicional
    }

    public PDDocument getPDDocument() {
        return docu;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            loadDocument();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hecho");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha habido un error");
            System.out.println(e);
        }  
    }
}

SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // Creo un objeto de la clase que realiza la tarea
        PDFLoader loader = new PDFLoader(jprogressBar, f);
        // Creo un hilo y lo inicio
        Thread thread = new Thread(loader);
        thread.start();    
        
        // Mientras el hilo está vivo, se recoge el progreso
        while (thread.isAlive()) {
            // Actualiza el progressbar en función del progreso
            int progress = (int)((float) loader.getPDDocument().getCurrentAccessPermission().getPermissionBytes());
            setProgress(progress);                  
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        // Actualiza el progressbar en la GUI
        jprogressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
    }
};

// Ejecuto el proceso.
worker.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

El ciclo `while` en la función `doInBackground()` se ejecuta en el subproceso principal, lo que hace que la GUI se detenga. El objetivo de `SwingWorker` es liberar el hilo principal de tareas pesadas, lo que permite que la interfaz de usuario siga respondiendo.

En lugar de un ciclo `while`, puede usar la función `Thread.join()` para esperar a que el subproceso secundario complete su ejecución antes de actualizar la barra de progreso en el subproceso principal. Para evitar problemas simultáneos, la barra de progreso del subproceso principal debe actualizarse mediante el método `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo actualizar correctamente la barra de progreso en el hilo principal:

```
File f = new File("ruta del fichero");

SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // Creo un objeto de la clase que realiza la tarea
        PDFLoader loader = new PDFLoader(jprogressBar, f);
        // Creo un hilo y lo inicio
        Thread thread = new Thread(loader);
        thread.start();
        // Espero a que el hilo termine de ejecutarse
        thread.join();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // Tarea en el hilo principal después de que se complete el hilo secundario
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hecho");
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        // Actualiza el progressbar en la GUI
        int progress = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        jprogressBar.setValue(progress);
    }
};

// Ejecuto el proceso.
worker.execute();
```

Espero que esto haya sido útil.